# Removing letters from two strings in python one by one

Tags: python

```
a = "ccdd"

b = "ccddcc"
```

I want to print:

```
a = " "

b = 'cc'
```

By removing 'c' from both strings until no more 'c' left in any one of the string.

Then remove 'd' as 'c' was removed

Comment: Can you explain "Then remove 'd' as 'c' was removed"? like if we remove 2 cs then remove 2 d's?

Comment: @python_learner it is said that we want to remove one by one. We should develop and algorithm instead of using that libs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
a = "ccdd"

b = "ccddcc"


def f(a, b):
    myList = list(set(a) & set(b))
    status = True
    while status == True:
        status = False
        if len(myList) > 0:
            status = True
            index1 = a.find(myList[0])
            index2 = b.find(myList[0])
            a = a[:index1] + a[index1 + 1:]
            b = b[:index2] + b[index2 + 1:]
            myList = list(set(a) & set(b))
    return a, b


a, b = f(a, b)

print(a)
print(b)
```

Answer (score 0):

When you know exactly `len(a) < len(b)`, you can try this:

```py
a = "ccdd"
b = "ccddcc"
while a and a[0] == b[0]:
     a = a[1:]
     b = b[1:]
```

Or you don't know which string will end first, try this:

```py
while (a and b) and a[0] == b[0]:
     a = a[1:]
     b = b[1:]
```

Here are just the code written based on what you're providing, and remove by order.